# Google search of "not intitle:" for terms present in content but not in title?

Tags: google-search, search-operators

Is there a way to search in Google for results that have not the terms in page title but in page content?

Namely something like "my term -intitle:my term" or "my term !intitle:my term"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you use `my term -intitle:"my term"` it will work.